# Load weights from layers with different names in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model consists of two different ResNets, and its layers share the same name but with a `d_` prefix at the beginning in one of the branches.

```
Image1----conv1---conv2---(...)
                                   \
                                     Other stuff I don't need the weights
                                   /
Image2----d_conv1---d_conv2---(...)
```

How do I load the same weights to both ResNet if my `weights.h5` file has those weights saved only with the name without prefix?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Keras while loading the weights set by_name=False.

Comment: Not possible. The models are different, so you will have an error telling you that you cannot load 100 layers in a model with 200 layers. (random numbers)

Comment: OK so you want to load say the 50-layer ResNet weight into 101-layer?

Comment: No, I have two different ResNet101 in the model. I have the weights from ResNet101 trained on COCO. Now I want to use those weights for both ResNet101.

Comment: That's strange. Is it possible to share the architecture?

Comment: It is pretty common while doing multimodal learning. Just look for rgbd cnn and all of them look like this: https://ai2-s2-public.s3.amazonaws.com/figures/2017-08-08/0b9af9b0ac87fafd9d7747d8047df38ee58dc647/1-Figure1-1.png